# HUP Signal on a process reading from cin

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I have an executable that reads input from std::cin in a loop always, I have a SIGHUP handler as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

void hupHandler(int)
{
    std::cout << "Handled sighup" << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    struct sigaction sigHupHandler{};
    sigHupHandler.sa_handler = hupHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sigHupHandler.sa_mask);
    sigHupHandler.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &sigHupHandler, nullptr);

    while(true)
    {
        std::string input;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        std::cout << "Read input \"" << input << "\"" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Child Exiting" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When i launch the executable on my terminal and send a SIGHUP using kill -HUP  I see that it handles the SIGHUP but after that i see an infinite print of the following -

```
$ ./child 
Handled sighup
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
Read input ""
```

Can someone please explain this behaviour to me? I actually need to have a process that runs in the background and constantly listen to its stdin (another process feeds to its stdin). I also need it to reload a config if it has been SIGHUP'd. I noticed that as soon as I HUP it it went in a loop of reading empty lines. So i wrote this utility to test and i see the same behaviour. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: perhaps look into using a [signalfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) for `SIGHUP`. You could then use an appropriate `select`/`poll`/`epoll` to monitor that file descriptor together with `STDIN_FILENO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just do anything you want in a signal handler. A signal handler can interrupt a program ***at any time***. Including when it's in a middle of doing something inside a C++ library function or a class, and none of the C++ library functions, templates, et al, are reentrant, like that. You, pretty much, cannot use any C++ library code, and certainly not `std::cout`, in a signal handler. You can't even do `new` or a `delete` of anything. That's the first problem, here.

Neither can you use C library functions either. They're not reentrant, either. The only thing you can do in a signal handler is use operating system calls, like open/close/read/write, et al. (basically, section 2 of man pages), directly.

Because of that, the shown code is undefined behavior, and you cannot expect it to work reliably, in any way, shape, matter, or form, as long as your signal handler does what it does.

Furthermore, when a process is in a middle of a system call itself (depending on the specific system call), a caught signal results in a failure with a specific `errno` of `EINTR`. This is described in your `signal(7)` manual page, which you should read. The C++ library will, most likely, interpret this as any other error reading from a file, and set the stream into a failed state, which looks like is the behavior you're seeing. You have to handle that yourself, too.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes - After it is interrupted i had to clear std::cin if fail() or eof() flag was set, and it works now!